# Xamarin iOS won't build. Sharing Violation on path for Asset Catalog file, Contents.json

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I keep getting a `MessagingRemoteException` when trying to build my iOS project. I think I have corrupted my Assets folder but I am not sure how to fix it.

Full Error:

```
MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build161000021 while executing a reply for topic xvs/build/execute-task/{PROJECT NAME}/4f35102002fACTool
IOException: Sharing violation on path /Users/{USERNAME}/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/{PROJECT NAME}/4f351024d5a644fefb1596ca1894dae6596bde2c8a00c5aeffbfb23a447eea48/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json
```

My `Assets.xcassets` folder contains a single `AppIcon.appiconset` folder. Inside, that folder, I have a `Contents.json` file, and a bunch of png images.

When I view the Asset Catalog in Visual Studio, I don't see any of my images.

I have cleaned my entire solution, manually deleted bin/obj folders, removed the project from the Cache folder on the Mac, and restarted everything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Create Icons again and drag and drop in Visual Studio Assets.xcassets folder.

Comment: I have done this numerous times. I get the MessagingRemoteException anytime I try to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in Visual Studio 16.10.0 Preview 1.0

I went back to 16.9.2, and everything worked immediately.

Comment: How did you go back to 16.9.2 Preview?

Comment: Ran into the exact same error when upgrading from 16.9.6 to 16.10.0 final today. Had to downgrade as well (requires uninstalling VS then downloading an older installer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history#installing-an-earlier-release)

Comment: The bug is under investigation, you can upvote the issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XamarinForms-ios:-IOException:-Sharing-/1355811

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 16.10.2 version fixes this.
I had the same issue. Some of these MS updates are big pains in a butt sometimes. They cannot just let this kind of critical issue happen all the time.. delaying the deployment and make developers frustrated..